Excel messes up formatting of a file exported from SPSS and processed by VBA
I decided to ask this question here because I'm seriously facing the waste of nearly 1 month of work due to unknown reasons. Moreover, I can't tell whether the problem lies in what SPSS does, my VBA code or just Excel.
SPSS, is a program that, among other usages, creates simple tables of aggregated data, formats those tables (using custom XML schema) and exports them to Excel or any suitable format. I wrote a VBA macro that performs some pretty extensive operations on an exported file. My goal is to create an XLSX, non macro file that... Well... Doesn't crash.
I can't post the code, not to mention that it's quite complex. However, here's what it does:

Scans the file to detect exported tables as they're only a set of cells. The macro detects tables by their titles which are the first cells of each table, with a specific formatting (Application.FindFormat). Addresses of those ranges are stored in a dictionary.
Creates named ranges for detected tables (loop through dictionary).
Creates a very hidden (xlSheetVeryHidden) IMGS worksheet that stores three pictures. 1st - an icon of worksheet (IMGS!$A$1), 2nd - an icon of table (IMGS!$A$2), 3rd - a PNG image (IMGS!$A$3). Icons are downloaded from Microsoft repository and placed in cells. Image is pasted from local disk path and embedded in a cell too.
Creates a table of contents (explained below).
Creates hyperlinks to each table (as VBA object - not Excel formula). Hyperlinks are added to titles (of detected tables) and they point to table of contents.
Groups rows of tables (Outline).
Formats other cells of specific properties (very unlikely to cause the problem).
Resets worksheets view (mainly Zoom and ScrollColumn/ScrollRow).

Table of contents is a first worksheet in the workbook. It's created by a macro that loops through newly added named ranges for tables (ThisWorkbook.Names). This worksheet has a ListObject with 5 columns:

Table number.
Hyperlink to the worksheet containing the table. It's a HYPERLINK formula that points to the $A$1 range of worksheet. As a Friendly_name it uses an icon of worksheet stored in IMGS!$A$1. Example: =HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(@CELL("address";FirstWorksheetWithTables!$A$1);"'";"");"]";"]'");"!$";"'!$");IMGS!$A$1).
Name of worksheet (just a string). It's used in the formula above.
Hyperlink to the table. It's a HYPERLINK formula that points to the first cell of a named range for each detected table. It's formatted in the same manner as previous hyperlinks column: =HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(@CELL("address";TABLE_NAMED_RANGE_001);"'";"");"]";"]'");"!$";"'!$");IMGS!$A$2).
Table title (just a string).

Additionally, the image from IMGS!$A$3 is placed in the cell above the ListObject.
When the macro finishes - it seems that everything went fine. However, when the file is saved or exported to XLSX and reopened (no matter the format), Excel notices that there are errors in the file:

We found a problem with some content in 'SPSS_file.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes).

After recovery, formatting of a couple of first worksheets (except table of contents or IMGS) is crashed and the extent of crash is unacceptable. The file becomes ugly and aesthetics is important in this case.
The file I'm working on contains around 70 worksheets and 450 tables. I tried to debug my code (both VBA and SPSS script) and file as much as possible but couldn't find the source of crash.
However, it's worth nothing that when SPSS exports tables to Excel, it creates lots of custom cell styles. For instance, the file I'm currently working on has nearly 3500 styles and the vast majority of them is created by SPSS. Sadly, I can't get rid of those styles because in effect formatting crashes even before I run the macro. Moreover, I observed that after recovery, styles of cells from crashed worksheets are changed to Normal. I doubt if the problem is caused by those first worksheets because when I deleted them and ran macro again, the result was the same.
Do you have any ideas where's the problem? What can I do?
Note: I work on SPSS 29.0.2.0 (20) and Excel 365 2410, compilation 18129.20030.

You have a list of a dosen steps in each of which a dosen things could have gone wrong... You'd really have to narrow this down in order to get effective help over here.
This being said - I'll throw a couple of ideas for you to try on the SPSS side

You don't have to work with a single output exported to Excel - during your SPSS analysis you can open and activate new output windows, which you can export to different sheets or different notebooks. This would enable you to separate the output into smaller units and possibly find a specific analysis (or analysis type) that is causing the trouble.
Consider - instead of working directly on the ouptut export file with the problematic formatting - the first step in your macro could be to copy the output with values only to a new workbook and continue from there.
In spss if you work with aggregation, restructure and with OMS facility you can get all the results as datasets and export from there instead of from the output. Use lots of conditional formatting in Excel instead of the SPSS output formatting.
Good luck...


I wrote a macro that identifies and adds unique cell styles based on SPSS Excel output and later deletes all SPSS-created styles. Now the workbook is stable and neither doesn't crash nor messes up formatting. So, it seems that the core of the problem are mainly styles.

Might as well add this comment as an answer to the question so maybe someone will have a chance to learn from your experience here.

Please review. I'm open to any modifications.

As @eli-k suggested, I'm posting conclusions of my analysis. So, the main problem is pretty general - Excel can make troubles if there are many cell styles created. The solution - however a bit twisted - is to 'auto'-detect unique/duplicated styles and reduce the total number of them.
Steps of code:

Iterate over all given cells.
Regarding merged cells - analyze only the first one.
Create an array that stores - selected by a user - properties of cell formatting.
Convert all array values to string.
Using any macro from here: hashing in VBA, convert array string to hash. This step is crucial for this code, because it creates unique style names as strings, so in fact combines values of various types (stored in array) into one. It also prevents from exceeding 255 characters limit.
Check if a style of this hash exists. If no - add it as a new cell style.
No matter if style already exists or not - apply style to analyzed cell.

Code:
Sub createApplyUniqueCellStyles( _
  rng As Range _
)

  'turning off ScreenUpdating and alerts
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With
  
  'Workbook variable
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = rng.Worksheet.Parent

  Dim cll As Range
  Dim rngToAnalyze As Range

  'arrays for formatting values
  'before running this macro, consider properties and total number of properties to identify unique styles from
  Dim arrStyleProperties(1 To 27) As Variant
  Dim arrStylePropertiesToString(1 To 27) As String
  Dim i As Long

  For Each cll In rng
    
    'skipping merged cells - except the first one
    If cll.MergeCells Then
      Set rngToAnalyze = cll.MergeArea

      If Not cll.Address = rngToAnalyze.Cells(1, 1).Address Then
        GoTo nextIteration
      End If

    Else
      Set rngToAnalyze = cll
    End If
    
    With rngToAnalyze

      'numbers format
      arrStyleProperties(1) = .NumberFormat

      'font
      With .Font
        arrStyleProperties(2) = .Name
        arrStyleProperties(3) = .FontStyle
        arrStyleProperties(4) = .Size
        arrStyleProperties(5) = .Color
        arrStyleProperties(6) = .Bold
        arrStyleProperties(7) = .Italic
        arrStyleProperties(8) = .Underline
      End With

      'alignment
      arrStyleProperties(9) = .HorizontalAlignment
      arrStyleProperties(10) = .VerticalAlignment

      'text wrapping
      arrStyleProperties(11) = .WrapText

      'merge
      arrStyleProperties(12) = .MergeCells

      'cell interior
      With .Interior
        arrStyleProperties(13) = .Color
        arrStyleProperties(14) = .Pattern
        arrStyleProperties(15) = .PatternColorIndex
      End With

      'borders
      'left
      With .Borders(xlLeft)
        arrStyleProperties(16) = .LineStyle
        arrStyleProperties(17) = .Color
        arrStyleProperties(18) = .Weight
      End With

      'right
      With .Borders(xlRight)
        arrStyleProperties(19) = .LineStyle
        arrStyleProperties(20) = .Color
        arrStyleProperties(21) = .Weight
      End With

      'top
      With .Borders(xlTop)
        arrStyleProperties(22) = .LineStyle
        arrStyleProperties(23) = .Color
        arrStyleProperties(24) = .Weight
      End With

      'bottom
      With .Borders(xlBottom)
        arrStyleProperties(25) = .LineStyle
        arrStyleProperties(26) = .Color
        arrStyleProperties(27) = .Weight
      End With

    End With

    'array values to text
    For i = 1 To 27
      If IsNull(arrStyleProperties(i)) Then
        'CStr() doesn't convert Nulls
        arrStylePropertiesToString(i) = "Null"
      Else
        arrStylePropertiesToString(i) = CStr(arrStyleProperties(i))
      End If
    Next i

    Dim strArrJoined As String
    Dim strArrJoinedMD5StyleName As String
    'array string
    strArrJoined = Join(arrStylePropertiesToString, "_")
    'array string hash
    strArrJoinedMD5StyleName = MD5(strArrJoined)

    Dim stl As Style
    On Error Resume Next
    Set stl = wb.Styles(strArrJoinedMD5StyleName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If stl Is Nothing Then
      'style not exists - add
      Set stl = wb.Styles.Add(strArrJoinedMD5StyleName, rngToAnalyze)

    End If
    
    'apply the style
    rngToAnalyze.Style = strArrJoinedMD5StyleName
   
    'release and erase
    Set stl = Nothing
    Erase arrStyleProperties
    Erase arrStylePropertiesToString

nextIteration:
  Next cll

  Set wb = Nothing
  Set cll = Nothing
  Set rng = Nothing
  Set rngToAnalyze = Nothing
  Erase arrStyleProperties
  Erase arrStylePropertiesToString
  Set stl = Nothing

End Sub

'https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA
Function MD5(ByVal sIn As String, Optional bB64 As Boolean = 0) As String
  'Set a reference to mscorlib 4.0 64-bit
  'Check that Net Framework 3.5 (includes .Net 2 and .Net 3 is installed in windows
  'and not just Net Advanced Services
      
  'Test with empty string input:
  'Hex:   d41d8cd98f00...etc
  'Base-64: 1B2M2Y8Asg...etc
      
  Dim oT As Object, oMD5 As Object
  Dim TextToHash() As Byte
  Dim bytes() As Byte
      
  Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
  Set oMD5 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
  
  TextToHash = oT.Getbytes_4(sIn)
  bytes = oMD5.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
  
  If bB64 = True Then
    MD5 = ConvToBase64String(bytes)
  Else
    MD5 = ConvToHexString(bytes)
  End If
      
  Set oT = Nothing
  Set oMD5 = Nothing

End Function

Function ConvToBase64String(vIn As Variant) As Variant
  'Check that Net Framework 3.5 (includes .Net 2 and .Net 3 is installed in windows
  'and not just Net Advanced Services
   
  Dim oD As Object
  Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
   
  With oD
    .LoadXML "<root />"
    .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.base64"
    .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
  End With
  
  ConvToBase64String = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")
    
  Set oD = Nothing

End Function

Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant
  'Check that Net Framework 3.5 (includes .Net 2 and .Net 3 is installed in windows
  'and not just Net Advanced Services
  
  Dim oD As Object
  Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
      
  With oD
    .LoadXML "<root />"
    .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
    .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
  End With
  
  ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")
    
  Set oD = Nothing

End Function

Concerning 5th step there are a couple of remarks:

Hash functions are not used for security, but uniqueness identification. Choose a function that suits you best. I used MD5 because it's the simplest.
Bear in mind that style name can be 255 characters long.
As Wikibooks article states, for Windows 10+ it's necessary to install Net Framework 3.5.
Consider converting hash string to base64. I chose not to convert, to avoid getting any potentially forbidden characters.

The code above can be used to reduce number of styles for any spreadsheet. However, code can take a lot of time to execute because it iterates over each cell from given range.
In the end, as it's SPSS-related question, I would recommend to delete all unused styles. Thankfully, SPSS styles have the same structure of name - style#*. Here's the code:
Sub deleteSPSSCellStyles()

  'turning off ScreenUpdating and alerts
  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With
  
  'Workbook variable
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook

  Dim stl As Style
  Dim strStyleName As String

  For Each stl In wb.Styles
    'no need to analyze built-in styles
    If Not stl.BuiltIn Then
      strStyleName = stl.Name
      If strStyleName Like "style#*" Then
        stl.Delete
      End If
    End If
  Next stl

  Set wb = Nothing
  Set stl = Nothing

End Sub

